# Why does Windows show the Common Name rather than the Organisation for "Issued To" when viewing a SSL certificate

Tags: windows, ssl-certificate

As per picture below, why does Windows use the CN (common name) rather than the O (organisation) for "Issued to:" when viewing an SSL certificate in Windows

[image: Viewing an SSL certificate in Windows]

Comment: If nothing else, the CN value is what used to get matched on for SSL/TLS.  And S/MIME certs in a company are all `O=This Company`, but `CN=Whose Cert This Is`

Comment: How does it help to see 172 certificates labeled "Stack Exchange Inc." if I am troubleshooting certificates for "superuser.com" and "stackoverflow.com"?